# Jsoup issue: cookie gets trimmed unexpectedly

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to login on site. I'm connecting to site using jsoup and getting response like this:

```
Connection.Response r1 = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/user/login")
                              .header("header1", "val1")
                              .data("password", "123")
                              .referrer("http://example.com/")
                              .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                              .execute();
```

And then getting cookie from response:

```
Map<String, String> cookie= r1.cookies();
```

Then pass this cookie to next request:

```
doc1 = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/")
            .cookies(cookie)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();
```

But I can't login because cookie is trimmed. I checked by sniffer requests and respons. I'm getting properly cookie, but pass trimmed. Where am I getting mistake?

cookie is in the hex encoding. it has one value - session, that stores other values in one encoded string. I decoded it and realize, that one of the values is empty(""). All values that come after him is cuted. What can I do whith that?

Comment: What do you mean by "trimmed cookies"? Can you add an example?

Comment: @TDG, cookie must contain the map - "session_id" and value(encoded string, length - 972 characters). But length of value in response is 416 characters.

Comment: If you didn't find a solution feel free to report this issue to Jsoup team: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/new